# Bitmap text compared to native caching

Tags: android, actionscript-3, caching, air, bitmap

I would love to have an answer to [this particular question, asked at the end of the thread](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=150918).
**TS** found the solution for transparent bitmap text him/herself, however, how does it compare to setting the **cacheAsBitmap** or **cacheAsBitmapMatrix** flag in performance?

Has anyone done some 'research' into this area? I know of the differences between cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix but i'd like to know where the bitmap text stands in all that!

Thanks! (And yes, the ultimate goal is optimal mobile performance :> )

Comment: while i'm not sure of the exact performance differentials, i'm certain that bitmap text, particularly for text that updates often, is faster on all deployment targets.  the Starling framework uses bitmap text for its TextField class.  Hopefully someone can post a more detailed response.

Comment: I'm baffled because... in the time it took you to type all this out, you could have simply tested it yourself.

Comment: @ AscensionSystems Yes, i probably could have, on 1000's of different phones, resolutions etc. :> Poor student here, only got one phone and that one's mine. So, i could indeed have tested in on my own phone. You got a point there.
@ TheDarkIn1978 i know, but they're still working on a mobile version of the starling framework. (big yeah when that comes out.) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bitmap text employs blitting techniques with the [BitmapData.copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) function.  this is always going to be faster than rendering vector text that is then converted to a bitmap.

---

**[EDIT RE:thanks]**

absolutely.  if you are creating content with AS3 for mobile you should definitely checkout the [Starling framework](http://gamua.com/starling/) (and here's the [documentation](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/)).  The `starling.text.TextField` class uses bitmap fonts from your own supplied texture atlas.

you should read Thibault Imbert's [Introducing Starling: Building GPU Accelerated Applications](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024217.do).  it's a short, free e-book that will get you up and running quickly.

Comment: Thanks! Could you point me in the direction of any good (AS3) libraries for above bitmaptext(that work on mobile)?

Comment: Ah yes, i know of starling, only: the starling.text.TextField is not supported on mobile, at least with starling 1.0. i've yet to test this on the just released 1.1 but i think it's still not supported :< any other Bitmap text libraries that work on mobile?

Comment: starling bitmap fonts absolutely work on mobile devices. :)... this might help:  http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/bitmap-font-dont-work-on-mobile-devices